# odbc_fetch_array(): SQL error is saying field refers to more than one table yet should not. Microsoft Access ODBC PHP

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

I have the following sql statement

```
$sql=
"SELECT wr.SortOrder, wr.webRequests_ID, wr.PQ_ID, pq.QText,wr.The_Answer, wr.webtmporders_detail_ID
FROM tbl_Preference_Questions as pq 
INNER JOIN tblwebtmporders_detail_Requests as wr ON pq.PQ_ID = wr.PQ_ID
WHERE wr.webtmporders_detail_ID = 42569
ORDER BY wr.SortOrder";
```

I get the records thru a function. the varialbe $mdbFilename is the path to the Access database.

```
$conn=odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename",'','',SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
$result_id = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
$results = all_odbc_rows($result_id);

function all_odbc_rows($result_id) 
{
  $tmp_arr = "";
  while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result_id)){
  
// this needs to be in my program code because ODBC / Access DB query will not accept escaping of single quotes.  single quotes 
// must be replaced by two single quotes for the sql passed to access via ODBC to work.

    foreach ($row as $k => $value)
    {
        $v = strip_tags($value);
        $row[$k] = str_replace("\\","",str_replace("'","''",$v)); 
    }
     $tmp_arr[] = $row;
  }
  return $tmp_arr;
}
```

yet I am getting the following PHP warning

```
odbc_fetch_array(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The specified field '`PQ_ID`' 
  could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement., SQL state S1000 
  in SQLGetData
```

If I run this sql in Microsoft Access Query builder, it returns 7 records with no problem.  Yet I get an error when I run the sql statement thru ODBC in PHP. I get the warning, and ODBC does not return any records.  Cannot work out why this join is not working?

I tried getting rid of the wr. and the pq. table identifiers and replaced them with the full table names in the sequel statement, but this did not work.

Any one have any ideas?

Thank you.

**btw, if I take the wr.PQ_ID field out of the sql statement, ODBC can run the query succesfully.**

This is very strange.

Here is the query builder in Access for this query I am trying to run in ODBC PHP
[image]

And SQL statement in in query builder in MS-Access
[image]
And the Result
[image]

So It works in MS Access, but not in ODBC call from PHP

weird.

Comment: I don't see how that can happen with the SQL you posted. It would happen if you didn't have `wr.` or `pq.` before all the references to `PQ_ID`.

Comment: i added that if I take the [wr.PQ_ID] column out of the SQL statement, ODBC can run successfully.  But I need the IDs in the form.  very strange

Comment: Do you get this error if you run the same query by hand, rather than from PHP?

Comment: if i run the query thru Access Database queyr builder, yes, the query returns 7 rows and can output the PQ_ID field.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a weakness in the ODBC interface with PHP. From the Microsoft doc: "SQLGetData retrieves data for a single column in the result set or for a single parameter after SQLParamData returns SQL_PARAM_DATA_AVAILABLE." Try aliasing the the `PQ_ID` column in your query: `wr.PQ_ID AS question_id,` or something like that.

Comment: Hi.  thanks for the suggestion.  I did try that.  It is not in the text of the SQL statement above, but it is shown in the graphic examples.  I am still stumped.  I aliased PQ_ID to PQID.  Maybe if I replace all the letters and symbols with something completely different?  wr.PQ_ID as jfld  ...  no underscores, no PQ, no ID.  will try that.

Comment: I tried a completely different alias - wr.PQ_ID as jfld - this did not work.  I wonder if the solution is that JOIN columns must be named differently for odbc_fetch_array() to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found someone on php.net that brought up the same issue.  Yet they were using SQL Server.  I am using MS-Access .mdb file.  They were able to use aliases with SQL Server database engine.  Aliases have not worked for me.  So I think the solution is that the joining fields / columns, must have different names, if using MS-Access Database, for ODBC odbc_fetch_array() or odbc_fetch_object() to work in a join sql statement.

[image]